# iptables - rules missing

Tags: linux, iptables, tor

I'm following [a guide for setting up a trasparent TOR proxy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TheOnionRouter/TransparentProxy) on my server.

There are several iptables rules in the guide, two of which are:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53

iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040
```

All the other rules appear just fine, but those two do not show up in iptables -L, even right after setting them.

Theres no error message or anything.

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are on the nat table, so:

```
iptables -t nat -L
```

will list them. This

```
iptables -L
```

is equivalent to:

```
iptables -t filter -L
```

There is also a `mangle` table, for "mangling" packets:

```
iptables -t mangle -L
```